# Is this true when I type `\kilo\gram\cdot\metre\per\second`?

Tags: siunitx

I see another way to type `\kilo\gram\metre\per\second`, see the problem 1.178:

[image]

I tried `\SI{10}{\kilo\gram\cdot\metre\per\second}`:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\SI{10}{\kilo\gram\cdot\metre\per\second}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this correct? How can I type it correctly?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for `inter-unit-product=\cdot`?